# Reactjs prop available in render but not in componentDidMount

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having a weird issue. When I call "UserShowStatsSuggestions" from this class:

```
var UserShowStatsPanelBody = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {data: []};
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        // Get the show
        var showUrl = "/api/v1/show/" + this.props.showStats.show + "/";
        $.ajax({
            url: showUrl,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                this.setState({data: data});
            }.bind(this),
            error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
            }.bind(this)
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        var statElements = [];
        // Create the user show stats
        if (this.props.showStats) {
            var showID = this.state.data.id;
            var showLink = "/leaderboards/show/" + showID + "/";
            var recapLink = "/recap/" + this.state.data.id + "/";
            statElements.push(<div className="row"></div>);
            statElements.push(<div className="row"></div>);
            statElements.push(<div className="row"></div>);
            statElements.push(<UserShowStatsSuggestions userID={this.props.userID} showID={showID} />);
            statElements.push(<div className="row"></div>);
        }

        return (
            <div>{statElements}</div>
        );
    }
});
```

I can access the prop "showID" in render, but not in componentDidMount:

```
var UserShowStatsSuggestions = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {data: []};
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        console.log(this.props);
    },
    render: function() {
        console.log(this.props);
        return (
            <div></div>
        );
    }
});
```

**From componentDidMount console.log**:

```
{userID: "107050829081899378766", showID: undefined}
```

**From render console.log**

```
{userID: "107050829081899378766", showID: 5705241014042624}
```

Any ideas why this would be the case?

Comment: Can't repro: http://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/4987/

Comment: I can not reproduce either. 
Are you certain that the render method runs exactly once? 
Could you show the code that renders the UserShowStatsSuggestions Component?

Comment: I just updated my post. I am pulling the "showID" from the state of another class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look if the console.log in render is executed more than once.

componentDidMount only runs once, so you will never see another console.log executed with the correct showID in componentDidMount.

However, render runs more than once, so you would see the console.log after the parents state has been updated, where showId no longer is null.

Modify your parents render method to not render before your ajax call has been completed.

Comment: I added the class that calls "UserShowStatsSuggestions". Sorry for leaving it out.

Comment: OK, I'm almost certain that your render method will run twice. Once when UserShowStatsPanelBody is mounted, once when the ajax call is complete. Try adding this in your render method ,
  if (this.props.showStats && this.state.data.length > 0)

Comment: Actually, it was better for me to change "getInitialState" to return {data: null} so that I didn't have weird type checking going on in the if statement. But you totally fixed my problem due to render being called before the state was updated! I'm marking your answer as correct, but you may want to tidy it up now that we've figured out what I did wrong :)